# Retrieve value from Multi-dimensional array php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this.

```
Array ( 
       [1] => Array ( 
                     [Stock Code] => 1Y 1111 
                     [Price] => 20 
                     [Quantity] => 10 
                     [Amount] => 200 
                    ) 

       [2] => Array ( 
                     [Stock Code] => 0300058 
                     [Price] => 30 
                     [Quantity] => 2 
                     [Amount] => 60 
                    ) 
      )
```

And here my code for retrieving the value from the array using foreach loop.

```
<?php
  $cartOutput = "";
  $i=0;
  foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item){
    $i++;
        $cartOutput = "Stock Code: ".$each_item['Stock Code']."<br/>";
        $cartOutput = "Price: ".$each_item['Price']."<br/>";
        $cartOutput = "Quantity: ".$each_item['Quantity']."<br/>";
        $cartOutput = "Amount: ".$each_item['Amount']."<br/>";
  }
?>
```

Here is where I display the result in HTML

```
<div style="height:500px;">
<?php echo $cartOutput; ?>
</div>
```

The output is:

Amount: 60

But I expected result is display all the value of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overwriting the variable in each iteration.Instead of that try to appened the value to the variable.Try like this

```
$cartOutput = "";
  $i=0;
  foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item){
    $i++;
        $cartOutput .= "Stock Code: ".$each_item['Stock Code']."<br/>";
        $cartOutput .= "Price: ".$each_item['Price']."<br/>";
        $cartOutput .= "Quantity: ".$each_item['Quantity']."<br/>";
        $cartOutput .= "Amount: ".$each_item['Amount']."<br/>";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your foreach loop you should have

```
$cartOutput .=
```

instead of just an =